How to correctly include SCSS mixin file in any SCSS file that is part of my Next.js app?
I have a working Next.js 14 app for which I am using SCSS. I have a main global.scss file in path:
my-project/src/app/globals.scss
and this file's content is:
/* my-project/src/app/globals.scss */
@use 'styles/mixins'; /* <-this is the mixins file I intend to use in any scss file listed below, but it's not working */
@use 'styles/global';
@use 'styles/navigation';
@use 'styles/footer';

as you can see, I @use several scss files located in path and they are imported just fine.
The issue I am having is with the styles/mixins.scss file, who's content looks like this:
/* my-project/src/app/styles/mixins.scss */
@mixin for-size($size) {
  @if $size == phone-only {
    @media (max-width: 899px) { @content; }
  } @else if $size == desktop-up {
    @media (min-width: 900px) { @content; }
  }
}


for example in styles/navigation.scss file I want to use the mixin like so:
header {
  &.navigation-bar {
    @include mixins.for-size(phone-only) {    
      padding: 0 1%;
    }
...


but I'm getting:
There is no module with the namespace "mixins".
the issue is that  I simply do not know how to correctly import/include/use the mixins.scss file so that  I can reference it's mixins from any scss file in my scss tree...any advice is appreciated.
